# Change the url of the backend but not the client one using Varnish

Tags: url, varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to manipulate the client url "www.example.com/download.." to "one.other.com/download...
But I want that the url on the client maintain the first "www.example.com/download"

Is there any way with Varnish 3 to do this??

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can easily do it using the `regsub()` function in VCL in `vcl_recv`.

For instance:

```
if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?example\.com" && req.url~ "^/download/") {
  set req.http.host = "one.other.com";
  set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/download/", "/");
}
```

This examples rewrites access to  `http://www.example.com/download/example.jpg` to  `http://one.other.com/example.jpg`. Of course, it is not visible to the user.

Comment: This results in a 302 being returned to the client for me with the altered URL. I'm trying to change the request that gets sent to my backend.